# Reload UIWebView from a popover view being displayed modally

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, reload, popover, synthesize

I have a viewController called mainViewController that contains a UIWebView called "myWebView". mainViewController presents a popover viewController called subViewController. In subViewController I have a button that is supposed to reload the myWebView. Doing something like this:

```
   mainViewController *vc = [[mainViewController alloc] init];
```

does not work because it creates another instance of mainViewController. How can I reload the myWebView in the mainViewController that is currently presenting the popover window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I misunderstood your question, this seems fairly easy to accoumplish. I suppose you could sent a notification from UIPopoverController.
First in your main view controller in viewWillAppear add self as observer:

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMyWebView:) name:@"reloadWebView" object:nil];
```

You have to implement method on your main view controller that will do actual reloading,
this would be

```
    - (void)realoadMyWebView:(NSNotification *)notification
```

make sure to remove yourself as a observer in viewWillDisappear

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];
```

then you can post a notification from you popover controller

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"reloadWebView" object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

Comment: I had already solved the issue. I also used notifications as you have suggested. Thanks